# ¿cómo agrego funcionalidad a los botones de un DialogFragment customizado?

Tags: java, android, dialog-fragment

Bien, pues tengo un RecyclerView con muchos elementos, y cada elemento tiene los datos de un objeto "Juego" (todo strings) y a la derecha un botón "Borrar"

Cuando hago click en el botón "borrar" de un elemento del Recycler, me crea un nuevo DialogFragment que recibe uno de los Strings de dicho elemento del Recycler (en este caso el título del juego, que muestra por pantalla en un Textview en el dialogFragment que se acaba de crear) a través de un bundle.

Además del Textview que muestra el título del juego y otro que muestra un "¿Estás seguro?", abajo hay 2 botones, uno quiero que simplemente cierre este dialog, el otro quiero meterle la acción de borrar el elemento de la BBDD (simplemente haría una consulta a mi BBDD con ese título y cuando encontrara la coincidencia que solo puede ser única, lo borraría)

Mi duda es dónde o cómo he de introducir dichos OnclickListener para poder introducir estas opciones.

Dejo el código:

clase SegurDialog (.java del Dialog personalizado)

```java
public class SegurDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private TextView ito;
    private Button buttonbtn1;
    private Button buttonbtn2;
    private String txt;

    public SegurDialog(){

    }

    public static SegurDialog newInstance(String texto){
        SegurDialog frag = new SegurDialog();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("texto",texto);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         txt = getArguments().getString("titl");


        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext()," "+txt,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_segur, null);
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        ito = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.juegorradotxt);
        ito.setText(txt);
```

El XML de dicha clase:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="252dp"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputitotito"
            android:layout_width="394dp"
            android:layout_height="84dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="¿Seguro que desea borrar el siguiente juego?"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/juegorradotxt"
            android:layout_width="392dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/inputitotito"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#C70000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="391dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/juegorradotxt"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:background="#0000FF"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnsiborr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="126dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="126dp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_dark_frame"
            android:text="BORRAR"
            android:textColor="#FF0000" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnoborr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:text="CANCELAR" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Dejo también el código del Adapter del RecyclerView:

```java
public class Adaptarecycler extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adaptarecycler.ViewHolder> {

    List<Juego> jueguis;
    private Context mcontext;

    public Adaptarecycler(Context mcontext,List<Juego> jueguis){

        this.jueguis = jueguis;
        this.mcontext = mcontext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_juego, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(v);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( final ViewHolder viewHolder,final int i) {
        final Juego j1 = jueguis.get(i);
        viewHolder.titltxt.setText(j1.getTitulo());

        viewHolder.btndelet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity)(mcontext);
                FragmentManager manager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();

                SegurDialog mdialog = new SegurDialog();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("titl",j1.getTitulo());
                mdialog.setArguments(b);

                mdialog.show(manager,"SegurDialog");
            }
        });

        viewHolder.titltxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(mcontext, Addmod.class);

                //Bundle b = new Bundle();
                //b.putParcelable("juego",j1);

                i.putExtra("jue",j1);
                mcontext.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return jueguis.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView titltxt;
        public ImageButton btndelet;
        public ViewHolder( View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            titltxt=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titltxt);
            btndelet=(ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btndelet);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que tienes que hacer es crear un evento que implementes en el adaptador y lo lances desde el dialog fragment cuando presiones uno de los botones.

Hacerlo es sencillo.

1. Lo primero que tienes que hacer es crear la interfaz que implementaras en el adaptador y que ejecutaras desde el dialog fragment.

   ```
   // Interfaz
   public interface OnClickButtonListener {

       void onClickButton();
   }
   ```
2. Lo segundo es configurar la interfaz en el dialog fragment, lo que incluye crear un objeto de la interfaz, crear el método a través del cual se implementara la interfaz y, por ultimo, ejecutar la interfaz cada vez que pulses el botón borrar.

   ```
   // Dialog fragment
   public class SegurDialog extends DialogFragment {

       ...

       // 1. Creas el objeto de la interfaz
       private OnClickButtonListener listener;

       ...

       @Override
       public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

           ...

           buttonbtn1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnsiborr);

           buttonbtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {

                   if (listener != null) {
                       // 3. Cada vez que pulses el botón borrar la interfaz se ejecutará
                       listener.onClickButton();
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       // 2. A través de este método implementaras la interfaz en el adaptador. 
       // Ten en cuenta que al implementar la interfaz la estas inicializando.
       public void setOnClickButtonListener(OnClickButtonListener listener) {
           this.listener = listener;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Y por ultimo implementar la interfaz en el adaptador.

   ```
   // Adaptador
   public class Adaptarecycler extends 
   RecyclerView.Adapter<Adaptarecycler.ViewHolder> {

       ...

       @Override
       public void onBindViewHolder( final ViewHolder viewHolder,final int i) {

           ...

           viewHolder.btndelet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {

                   FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity)(mcontext);
                   FragmentManager manager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();

                   SegurDialog mdialog = new SegurDialog();
                   Bundle b = new Bundle();
                   b.putString("titl",j1.getTitulo());
                   mdialog.setArguments(b);

                   // Implementas la interfaz
                   mdialog.setOnClickButtonListener(new OnClickButtonListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClickButton() {

                           // Aquí implementas tu lógica de borrado
                       }
                   }

                   mdialog.show(manager,"SegurDialog");
               }
           });

           ...
       }

       ...
   }
   ```